# Python: how to solve ImportError

Tags: python, class, import

I have the following class in a file named `SymbolManager.py`:

```
from qgis.core import *

class SimbolManager:
  def __init__(self):
    self.initSymbols()

  def initSymbols(self):
    self.symbolMap = {}
    props = {'color': '0,0,200'}
    self.symbolMap['SimpleVertex'] = QgsMarkerSymbolV2.createSimple(props)

    props = {'width': '1', 'color': '0,0,255'}
    self.symbolMap['SimpleLine'] = QgsLineSymbolV2.createSimple(props)

  def getSymbolRenderer(self, name):
    symb = self.symbolMap[name]
    if symb is not None:
      return QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(symb)
    return None
```

From a file in the same dir I'm trying to import `SymbolManager` this way:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from Ui_OsmNavigator import Ui_OsmNavigator

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *

import DbConnection

from SymbolManager import SymbolManager  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

When I run the script, from inside QGIS it gives me the following error:

> line 28, in 
>       from SymbolManager import SymbolManager ImportError: cannot import name SymbolManager

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please use `pyflakes` or `pylint`, preferrably in a way that is integrated with your editor (Emacs+`flymake`+`pyflakes`+`pep8` make an awesome on-the-fly checker, for example). P.S. using of `import *` is strongly discouraged by PEP8—it will delay failed imports to where you try to use them, so instead of of `"Cannot import name FOO"` you get `"NameError: FOO"` later during the execution.

Comment: Also, I suspect your `getSymbolRenderer` might be faulty: `symbolName[name]` will raise an error if `name` is not found in the dictionary. Your later check `if symb is not None` will not help. Instead I would use `return QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(self.symbolMap[name]) if name in self.symbolName else None`.

Comment: @ErikAllik: thanks for the suggestions. As you can imagine, I'm not a python dev at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your class isn't called `SymbolManager`?

```
class SimbolManager: 
      ^^^^^^
```

Comment: So what would a compiler have told you instead of "cannot import"? Perhaps "Cannot import because you accidentally typo-ed up your class name"?